# How to check whether key exist in hasharray and have specific value - Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, key

I have hash array:

```
my %hash = (
    'DISK'    => 1,
    'MEMORY'  => 1,
    'CPU'     => 0,
    'SSL'     => 1,
    'PROCESS' => 1,
);
```

Function:

```
sub fun
{
    my $self = shift;
    my @ret = ();
    my $index = 0;
    my ($alarm, $hash) = @_;
    my $key = "CPU";

    print "Key: $_ and Value: $hash->{$_}\n" foreach (keys %{$hash});

    foreach my $name (keys %{$self->{ServerParameters}})
    {
            my $par = uc $name;
            $par =~ s/\d$//g;

            if (!defined ${${$self->{ServerParameters}}{$name}}{$alarm})
            {
                    next;
            }
            if (${${$self->{ServerParameters}}{$name}}{$alarm} eq "1")
            {       
                    if (exists $hash{$par}){
                        if ($hash{$par} == 0){
                            print "VALUE 0\n";
                        }
                    }
                    my $param = ${$self->{ServerParameters}}{$name}->getValues();
                    $ret[$index++] = "Alarm parameter: $par : $param";
            }
    }
    return @ret;
}
```

I'm passing hash array to above function:

```
fun("Red", \%hash);
```

At first I'm trying to check whether specific key exist and then if value of it is 0. When trying to run above code I receiving:

Global symbol "%hash" requires explicit package name

How can I do similiar check using e.g grep ? Thank for any asistance.

Comment: Your `$hash{$par}` implies that there is a hash `%hash`, which there isn't; thus the error message. Since you have the `$hash` _reference_ you need to dereference, `$hash->{$par}`

Comment: `${${$self->{ServerParameters}}{$name}}{$alarm}` is much nicer written as `$self->{ServerParameters}{$name}{$alarm}`

Answer (score -1):

When you do this:

```
fun("Red", \%hash);
```

You're sending in a hash *reference*, not a hash. There's two ways to fix this.

One, the easiest, send in the hash. I would recommend using the second approach below, unless you've got a lot of code/many subroutines to update.

```
fun("Red", %hash);
```

...then change:

```
my ($alarm, $hash) = @_;
```

to:

```
my ($alarm, %hash) = @_;
```

That'll alleviate any other code changes.

Second, instead of changing the call and the assignment of the parameter(s) per the example above, you will have to change all uses to the hash within your code to a hash reference. For example:

```
if (exists $hash->{$par}){
    if ($hash->{$par} == 0){
        print "VALUE 0\n";
    }
}
```

There's no real right or wrong way, it really depends what you're doing with the code inside of the subroutine.

Sending in a hash makes a copy (ie. you now have two instances of the hash floating around, which may be problematic depending on the size of the hash. In this case, it's negligible to say the least). Changing the data in the hash within the sub does not change the outer-scoped hash.

Sending in a reference does not make a copy which reduces memory footprint, but any changes to the hash reference within the sub will change the original hash outside of the sub.

Comment: Don't go about copying hashes just to avoid using `->`! `fun("Red", \%hash);` was the correct approach; the problem is with `fun`.

Comment: Passing an entire hash's contents to recontruct a duplicate within the subroutine is wasteful and unnecessary. Please don't advise that people do stuff like this

Comment: So, if you do need a duplicate, what will you do... copy it internally anyway? What if I want to construct inline: `Blah->sub({ a => 1, b => 2});` What if I don't want the braces in my call? Force the user to write the hash first then send in a ref? There are many use cases for this. What if I have an external event I'm sending to or any other reason?

Comment: You've sent a hash ref there too.